# Return value register and destructor call order

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am implementing my own atomic class as on a particular project *in which I don't have access to the C++11 atomic library*.  I have the following code so far:

```
 class CAtomicLong
 {
 public:

     CAtomicLong(long lVal) : m_lValue(lVal) {}

     long operator+(long lVal)
     {
         CAutoLock lock(m_lock);
         m_lValue += lVal;
         return m_lValue;
     }
 private:

     CMyMutex m_lock;
     long m_lValue;
 };
```

Assume that `CMyMutex` is a custom wrapper around a mutex, and `CAutoLock` is a class whose destructor unlocks the object passed to it during its construction.  Those details are largely irrelevant for this question anyway.

What I would like to know is if it is safe to return `m_lValue` like this; i.e. will it be copied into a register to return *before* the destructor for `lock` is called?  I ask as I am concerned about torn reads and writes, because if the destructor is called *before* the return register is setup another thread could start modifying `m_lValue` as it is being copied for return.

I have had a look at the disassembly in Visual Studio for code like this and it appears to show the return call being made *before* the destructor is called, but a) I don't really know what I'm looking at with assembly (I'm still learning :)) and b) I don't know if this is standard behaviour (again, I'm still learning).  The safest workaround to this *potential* problem is

```
long operator+(long lVal)
{
    CAutoLock lock(m_lock);
    long lTemp = (m_lValue += lVal);
    return lTemp;
}
```

...but if this is overkill I'd rather know now.

Comment: Which platform are you on? Most of them have an intrinsic for atomic increment and fetch which you can use instead of a mutex

Comment: This has to work on Windows, Solaris Sparc and Linux.  I know there are atomic increment functions on Windows but cannot find an atomic retrieval function, nor do I have access to the required functions on Solaris.  Hence this question.

Comment: There are no "registers" in C++. The code is correct as written.

Comment: Why is `operator+` modifying the class? Should it have been `operator+=`?

Comment: @James Adkison, yes it should be +=.  Good spot on the typo :)

Comment: @Dani if you have any more information about atomic operations that could be of use in my other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202309/functions-to-atomically-read-a-value) please do post there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is correct. [stmt.return]/3 says:

> The copy-initialization of the result of the call is sequenced before the destruction of temporaries at the end of the full-expression established by the operand of the return statement, which, in turn, is sequenced before
>   the destruction of local variables (6.6) of the block enclosing the return statement.